# Determine node name from text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a use case where a user can select some text in a `p` element and I need to toggle 'bold' it - ie, if it's NOT bold, make the text bold and vice-versa. Is there a way to determine the node type/name from the selected text?

For example: in the below example, when the user selects 'Foo' I want to know that a `span` has been selected. If the user selects 'Bar'; I want to know that a `p` was selected. If the user selects 'Foo B'; I want to know that a `p` was selected.

```js
$('#toggle-bold').click(function() {

   // The following will always add a new span wrapping the selected text then make it bold
   
   var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
   // Anyway to determine the node type/name of the selected text?
   var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
   var span= document.createElement("span"); 
   span.appendChild(selectedText); 
   selection.insertNode(span);
        
   $(span).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true">
    <span>Foo</span> Bar
</p>

<button id="toggle-bold">Toggle Bold</button>
```

Comment: For this specific use case, you can replace all of the code in that event handler with `document.execCommand("bold");` (although in most browsers it'll insert `<b>...</b>` rather than a span with `font-weight`)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, didn't know about that. Eventually I will need for more control so, I will be able to say `set font-weight to 600`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object has two properties for this: [`startContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/startContainer) (the node where the range starts) and [`endContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endContainer) (the node where it ends). Then you can get the node name via the `nodeName` property. (You may or may not want to use `parentNode` if the node in question is a Text node.) So for instance, since your `selection` variable actually references a `Range` (not a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)):

```
console.log("Start node's nodeName: " + selection.startContainer.nodeName);
console.log("End node's nodeName: " + selection.endContainer.nodeName);
```

Often, again, those will show `"#text"` because the range may be in a Text node.

```js
$('#toggle-bold').click(function() {

  // The following will always add a new span wrapping the selected text then make it bold

  var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  // Anyway to determine the node type/name of the selected text?
  console.log("Start node's nodeName: " + selection.startContainer.nodeName);
  console.log("End node's nodeName: " + selection.endContainer.nodeName);


  var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.appendChild(selectedText);
  selection.insertNode(span);

  $(span).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true">
  <span>Foo</span> Bar
</p>

<button id="toggle-bold">Toggle Bold</button>
```

`Range` also tells you *where* in those container elements the range starts and ends (via `startOffset` and `endOffset`).

Comment: thanks, on firefox this always seems to output `#text` even when I select a `span`

Comment: @JakeM: As I said above, if you want to know the parent element's node name, use `parentNode` to get to it and then read its `nodeName`. But I suspect even on Firefox, it's *possible* to get something other than a text node (and I know it is on Chrome). So for instance `var name = selection.startContainer.nodeName; if (name === "#text") { name = selection.startContainer.parentNode.nodeName; }` Or rather than the name you could check the type: `var name = selection.startContainer.nodeType === 1 ? selection.startContainer.nodeType : selection.startContainer.parentNode.nodeType;`